# How to Update Instance in code after Insert and Workflow Rule?

Tags: workflow

I want to test my Workflow Rule.
This Workflow should always edit value of field after every insert or update.

```
Foobar__c f = new Foobar__c();
f.loremIpsum__c = 'Dolor';
insert f;
// workflow rule should edit now the value of field loremIpsum__c to 'NotDolorAnymore'
System.assertEquals('NotDolorAnymore',f.loremIpsum__c);
```

How to pass this test?

Comment: Please @Moderators to delete this Question. The problem is somewhere else, than I expected the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the Test class,

use the Try and Catch statements like below...

```
//Give the Code with dummy values for the Object and insert in TRY
try{
    insert f;
}
catch(DmlException e){
    System.assertEquals(e.getMessage().contains('NotDolorAnymore'),e.getMessage());
//You can use the System.asserts over here on your wish according to your scenario...
}
```

Hope this might helps...

Comment: After that code, I see that my Workflow is propably not running.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-query the record before doing the assertion. This will grab the new database values. Insert will only update the Id.

```
f = [SELECT loremIpsum__c from Foobar__c where Id = :f.Id];
```

Comment: It should help, I think, but it does not :( Maybe my Workflow is corrupted, because it looks like it never runs.